Android CLT: SDK Manager not found
I have installed Android Command Line Tools on Windows 10. I am unable to install Android Studio.
I have then installed the files needed to run Android Command Line Tools. When I run flutter doctor -v, I receive the output:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4355], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.19.6 on channel stable at C:\Users\myUser\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 54e66469a9 (2 weeks ago), 2024-04-17 13:08:03 -0700
    • Engine revision c4cd48e186
    • Dart version 3.3.4
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22.0.1+8-jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-22.0.1+8 (build 22.0.1+8)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.35)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 version 16.11.34729.46
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4355]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 124.0.6367.118
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 124.0.2478.67

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

This means all of the files needed to run Android Command Line Tools are installed. Android Studio isn't installed but it isn't necessary.
When I attempt to use Android Command Line Tools, there is an error, because the sdkmanager can't be found. However, the sdkmanager file is located at C:\Program Files\Android\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat
The directory containing the sdkmanager.bat file is added to the system PATH variable.
I have run the command sdkmanager --version, which returns sdkmanager: command not found
I have attempted to reinstall the Android Command Line Tools and flutter, which has not worked.

If you are using Windows, the command for sdkmanager is sdkmanager.bat
Similarly, the command for avdmanager is avdmanager.bat
